# Adding buttons at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I want to place a few buttons on my form.  The number is unknown at design time.  Actually each button will represent an item entered in combo box. So if user adds an item, a button on the form should be added by the code.
Please advise how to do it?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply looping over any number (in this case from a combo box) and creating the required number of buttons before adding them to the form.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To myComboBox.Items.Count - 1
   Dim newButton = new Button()

   // Add some properties, etc. to the button
   newButton.Text = myComboBox.Items(i).ToString()

   MyForm.Controls.Add(newButton)
Next
```

Comment: +1 because this is a perfectly reasonable way of doing this. However, it makes more sense to me to add the button corresponding to the item that has just been added to the `ComboBox`, rather than looping through all of the existing items and adding a button. All you need to do is create the button and add it to your form's `Controls` collection in the same place where you add an item to your `ComboBox`.

Comment: Good point Cody. In my head I had it that the user was selecting some integer value in the combo box and we were creating the buttons based on that number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
Sub AddButton(ByVal label As String, ByVal location As Point)

Dim b As Button

b = New Button
b.Location = location
b.Text = label
Me.Controls.Add(b)

End Sub
```

Comment: Also see the question:

"Dynamic button click event handler"     ...    

since you probably want to handle the event generated by a click on one of the new buttons.

Comment: Can I just point out, you'd be better off using ```with```...so ```Dim b As Button With {.Name = "Button1", .Size = New Size(30,30), .Location = New Point(12,100)}```